# Errormessage when counting n

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to filter my participants by their age. For this, I used (e.g.):

```
patientage <- c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 30, 31, 32, 34)

group_by(patientage) %>%  count(patientage) %>% filter(patientage >17 & patientage <31)%>% sum(n)
```

Now I want to use `sum(n)` to count all the participants between 18-30. But this leads to an error code:

```
> Error in as.vector(x, mode) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to
> vector of type 'any'
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your data and the code how you actually tried to do `sum(n)`?

Comment: What is `n` in this case? You might be looking for `mutate(Count = n())`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I am a newbie so I edited my post, hoped it helps. n in this case shows me the sum of the appearing single ages. But I want to have all this n's (so all the ones who are between 18 and 30 years old) sum up. I tried to do mutate(count=n()) but it does not seem to sum them up but does something else instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `dplyr` expects dataframes as input, so you have to convert your vector:

```
patientage <- data.frame(
  patientage = c(
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
    28, 29, 30, 30, 31, 32, 34
  )
)
```

Now you can work with your data. By the end, `sum()` expects a vector back again, that's why you need to `pull()` the desired vector out of the dataframe before summing:

```
patientage %>% 
  group_by(patientage) %>% 
  count(patientage) %>% 
  filter(patientage > 17 & patientage < 31) %>% 
  pull(n) %>% 
  sum
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This solved my problem. Unfortunately, I am not able to upvote your answer yet.